# AVR USART: Make data register flexible

Tags: c++, arduino, usart

I have a library which can write to a serial port on an arduino. It uses an assignment of the form

```
#define UDRn UDR0
....
void write(uint8_t data) {
    UDRn = data;
}
```

for writing. As far as I understand, UDR0 is the data register for serial port 0. The #define means UDRn will be this data register. The library has a flag to change UDRn to be UDR1 at compile time.

However, I would like to use the same library to write different data to Serial0 and Serial1. So I need to be able to have one instance which writes to UDR0, and one which writes to UDR1. Is it possible to unify this?

Something like:

```
class Writer {
    public:
        write(uint8_t);
    private:
        register target;   
}

void Writer::write(uint8_t data) {
    target = data;
}
```

E.g. Can I have pointers to registers?

Comment: Yes. The register macros are basically something like this... `(*(volatile uint8_t *)(mem_addr))`. All the registers are mapped into the memory address space. You can even have a template with the register pointers as parameters.

Comment: Yes, and it worked! Unfortunately I can't accept a comment.